# Nested attributes and interacting with form hash and setting the user_id to current_user.id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have rewritten this question as the other one seemed too verbose. I have the following model structure and am interested in having a set of files uploaded (2 at a time via a builder). I am not sure if the polymorphic relat

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assets, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:asset].blank? } 
  attr_accessible :assets_attributes, :asset

  ...
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
   attr_accessible :name, :user_id, :description ...

   ...
end
```

I have copied out the entirety of the form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/arc/items/70" class="edit_item" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_item_70" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="NnaCxwmfy2zT8MnN7oNQnOx0xYXkgKUs+NbIh8+8cL4=" /></div>
  <div class='files'>
        <input id="item_assets_attributes_70_asset" name="item[assets_attributes][70][asset]" type="file" />
        <input id="item_assets_attributes_70_description" name="item[assets_attributes][70][description]" size="30" type="text" />


        <input id="item_assets_attributes_71_asset" name="item[assets_attributes][71][asset]" type="file" />
        <input id="item_assets_attributes_71_description" name="item[assets_attributes][71][description]" size="30" type="text" />
</div>
<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Update Menu item" />
</form>
```

and here is the controller for interacting with it:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
...
def update
  item=params[:item]
  item[:assets_attributes].values do |v|
    v[:asset][:user_id]=3 # just hard-code it to see if workig
  end

  if @item.update_attributes(item)
    flash[:notice]="Menu Item has been updated #{undo_link}"
  else 
    flash[:notice]="Menu Item has not been updated"
  end
end
```

In my asset class, the user_id NEVER gets set. How would I make this work? I obviously want to get the current_user.id.

thx

**edit #1**

Using Rails 3.1

**edit 2**

One thing that I've noticed is that if I set an instance variable in the loop and then debug it into the view, it wasn't set meaning that this loop isn't even running.

```
item[:assets_attributes].values do |v|
  v[:user_id]=3
  @a="here is a string"
end
```

I have also updated the Item model with the appropriate attr_accessible for the item class.

Answer (score 1):

In this block you're not doing anything.

```
item[:assets_attributes].values do |v|
  v[:user_id]=3 # just hard-code it to see if working
end
```

`values` is just returning the values, so you need to have an iterator like `each` if you want to interact with those values. Try this

```
item[:assets_attributes].values.each do |v|
  v[:user_id]=3 # just hard-code it to see if working
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that you cannot mass assign user_id. Either:

You have attr_accessible defined, and it does not include user_id
You have attr_protected defined, and it does include user_id
You are using Rails 3.2, which does this automatically to prevent reassigning an object to a different user via mass assignment (which is a security hole).

If that is the case, then your best bet is to set the user directly via `asset.user=` instead (or to allow user_id to be mass assigned, I suppose).

Comment: thx Shaun, I have user_id in attr_accessible (updated above) and am using Rails 3.1 - I'm pretty sure there is a syntax issue with iterating over the assets. Maybe assigning asset.user makes sense and then assinging `self.user_id=self.user.id` in a default_values before_save?

Comment: Assigning asset.user is the same thing as setting asset.user_id to that user's ID. You don't need to set user_id explicitly as well - Rails will handle it.